# Centering Alignment Columns

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering four rows. What I've done as a temporary measure is define a margin percentages in css as .left and .right and tried to just visually center it, that isn't going to work...

On the forum I've done this for not only are the rows not properly centered, when you zoom into the columns they all begin to align in one row (instead of being like table).

I've been trying to fix this for the past hour or so with no luck. Any help? I really, really appreciate it. Thanks.

sandbox: http://cssdesk.com/C5Kmk

Edit:

If I could do a table like the one I made, then I would... but I'm pretty new to coding and I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Also, I put the link there because I'm having difficulty posting the code.

Edit 2:

The html/css code ended up centering the columns, but it also aligned them a single row.

The .left code almost worked. There are still some problems when someone zooms in. For example, the right 2 columns begin to disappear so that only the left two remain. Also, a floating main menu bar that's on the forum drops below the column-- and while everything is centered on columns/code below it, it is not actually centered on the forum, rather it's dead set to the very left...

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Have you thought of just using a table element?

Comment: why you using  `margin-left: 15%;` on `.left` class? by removing the property all appear in same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are using this property in `.left` class.

```
.left {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
```

replace with this style. what this property will do? it will make the center everything..

```
.left {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
width:1024px;
min-width:auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the DEmo.. http://cssdesk.com/GGnx5

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Uu2be/)

Try following the HTML structure below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cf">
        <div class="ptable">
            PTABLE
        </div>
        <div class="ptable">
            PTABLE
        </div>
        <div class="ptable">
            PTABLE
        </div>
        <div class="ptable">
            PTABLE
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="YOUR_ACTION_URL">
        FORM CONTENT
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cf:after {
    /* helps clearing the floats */
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.container {
    width: 400px; /* width of its content*/
    margin: 0 auto; /* will give auto margins on both left and right which will center it */
}

.ptable {
    float: left;
    width: 100px /* Feel free to adjust this as per your requirents. 100*4 = 400px */
}

form {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The html/css code ended up centering the columns, but it also aligned them a single row.

The .left code almost worked. There are still some problems when someone zooms in. For example, the right 2 columns begin to disappear so that only the left two remain. Also, a floating main menu bar that's on the forum drops below the column-- and while everything is centered on columns/code below it, it is not actually centered on the forum, rather it's dead set to the very left...

Any idea of what's going on?

Picture of the problem: http://s1335.photobucket.com/user/dnpranks/media/Untitled15_zps89a1c5e9.png.html?sort=3&o=0

-It maybe be hard to see in the picture but the very left column is at the edge of the html page, the forum background is next to it.